# Installing QGIS through Anaconda on Mac OS, incompatible library version

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, conda

I am using Conda 22.11.1 on my Mac and installed QGIS using `conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" qgis` in a new conda environment titled `qgis_personal` just for QGIS. When I use the command `qgis` to open the application, I receive this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libwebp.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/anaconda3/envs/qgis_personal/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libtiff.5.dylib requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libwebp.7.dylib provides version 8.0.0
zsh: abort      qgis
```

This is what is on my conda list for libwebp

```
libwebp                   1.0.2                hd3bf737_5    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.1.0                         2    conda-forge/label/cf202003
```

When I attempt to upgrade libwebp, nothing changes, it seems as though this is the most recent libwebp.

Any help on this?